# How do I convert a .csv file to a javascript array of dictionaries. Keys of each dictionary are column headers in the .csv file and items are values

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

For example, if I had a .csv file where the column headers are mentioned in the first row of the file and their subsequent values are specified in the following rows like so,

```
index,id,description,component,service
0,5,lorem ipsum,7326985,Field Service
```

Comment: This question is marked as python, but should probably not be since it seems like you're asking about Javascript objects.

Comment: You can use a package like [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson). It's pretty extensive - there might be other lightweight packages available too in case all you want in your application is simple csv to json conversion

Comment: If you were using powershell, it would be as easy as this:
  Import-Csv Myfile.csv | ConvertTo-Json | Out-file JsonFile.js
If you don't want to write to a file, just leave out the last part.
Unfortunately, this brackets each item in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to separate out the data and the column headers. I'm going to make the assumption that the csv is stored in your program as an array of strings, each representing a line, i.e.

```js
const csv = [
  "index,id,description,component,service",
  "0,5,lorem ipsum,7326985,Field Service"
]
```

If your CSV isn't already represented this way, you can achieve this with the `fs` module:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./data.csv', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }

  const csv = String(data) // convert the buffer to a string
    .split('\n') // Split the string into an array where each item contains one line
    .filter(Boolean); // Remove any empty lines

  // Do the rest of the operations on the CSV data here
});
```

In which case we can split them up easily using the spread operator, after splitting each string on the commas:

```js
const [ headers, ...data ] = csv.map(row => row.split(','));
```

Now our objects look something like this:

```js
// headers
[ 'index', 'id', 'description', 'component', 'service' ]

// data
[ 
  [ '0', '5', 'lorem ipsum', '7326985', 'Field Service' ]
]
```

And we can now go ahead and map each of the arrays in the data array to an object, using each value's index to map it to a specific heading from the CSV.

```js
data.map(row => {
  const rowObject = {};
  row.forEach((value, index) => {
    rowObject[headers[index]] = value;
  });
  return rowObject
});
```

We of course have to return this mapped data object somewhere, or assign it to a new variable as the `Array.map()` function does not update the original array but creates a new one. Putting it all together into a code snippet it could look like this:

```js
const csv = [
  "index,id,description,component,service",
  "0,5,lorem ipsum,7326985,Field Service"
];

function csvToJSON(csv) {
  const [headers, ...data] = csv.map(row => row.split(','));
  return data.map(row => {
    const rowObject = {};
    row.forEach((value, index) => {
      rowObject[headers[index]] = value;
    });
    return rowObject
  });
}

console.log(csvToJSON(csv));
```